# Using oauth2_access_token to get connections in linkedIn

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get **the connections in linkedIn using their API**, but when I try to retrieve the connections  I get a 401 unauthorized error.

in the official documentation says

> You must use an access token to make an [authenticated call](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) on behalf
>   of a user
>
> **Make the API calls** You can now use this access_token to make API calls on behalf of this user by appending
>   "oauth2_access_token=access_token" at the end of the API call that you
>   wish to make.

The API call that I'm trying to do is the following

Error -->
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,headline,first-name,last-name)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=**access_token**

I have tried to do it with the following endpoint without any problems.

OK --> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,date-of-birth,industry,email-address,location,headline,picture-urls::(original))?format=json&oauth2_access_token=**access_token**

this list of endpoints for the connections API are described here
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api
I just copied and pasted one endpoint from there, so the question is what's the problem with the endpoint for getting the connections? what am I missing?

EDIT:
for the preAuth Url I'm using

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=**ConsumerKey**&scope=**r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_network&state**&state=**NewGuid**&redirect_uri=**Encoded_Url**

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=**QueryString_Code**&redirect_uri=**EncodedCallback**&client_id=**ConsummerKey**&client_secret=**ConsumerSecret**

please find attached the login screen requesting the permissions

[image]

EDIT2:
Switched to https and worked like a charm!

Comment: switched to HTTPS and got rid of this error as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access tokens are issued for a specific `scope` that describes the extent of the permission you are requesting. When you start the authentication transaction, you add a specific parameter (called **scope**) that requests the user to consent access to what you want (in this case their connections). If I remember correctly, in LinkedIn that is `r_network`.

Check their documentation here: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting

So, your call is perfectly ok, but very likely your **access_token** doesn't have enough privileges.

Comment: thanks for the reply! please take a look to my update! I'm using the r_netowrk indeed!

Comment: got it! I just copied and pasted the url into the broser got the exception of ssl needed! XD just a small detail! switched to https and worked!

Comment: Does LinkedIn provide API's (publically or in partner program) to get all contacts (mainly 1st)? Previously they provide such API's but in 2015, they revoked that.

Answer (score 2):

```
apiHelper.getRequest(getActivity(),"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections?modified=new", new ApiListener() {
        @Override
        public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {
        }
    });
```

If you are trying to get user connections using the LinkedIn SDK for android like in the snippet above,

Check for permissions in the SDK in this class com.linkedin.platform.utils.Scope.

Make sure *r_network* is available when building your scope. Example

```
    public static final LIPermission R_NETWORK = new LIPermission("r_network", "Your network");
```

Can now be used like this to build scope

```
Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.W_SHARE, Scope.R_FULLPROFILE, Scope.R_CONTACTINFO, Scope.R_NETWORK)
```