# "NoneType" Object has no attribute error by python linkedinapi

Tags: python, linkedin-api

Now I am trying to use linkedin python api to get users' information, below is my code:

```
from linkedin import linkedin

API_Key='...'
API_Secret='...'
Return_url='http://localhost:8000'

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_Key, API_Secret, Return_url, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
print(authentication.authorization_url)  # open this url on your browser
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
application.get_profile()
```

However, it show the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access_token'

And another problem is, if i have a name of the person, how to use api to get the person's information?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the rep to comment, but see this answer: [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

This is the equivalent of a null pointer exception in java. Whatever object you are trying to access "access_token" field, it is null. If that object is what's returned from a function call, perhaps that function call failed.

Also see [Authenticate to linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530946/authenticate-to-linkedin)

[problems with LinkedIn API connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068840/problems-with-linkedin-api-connection)

[Using oauth2_access_token to get connections in linkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613467/using-oauth2-access-token-to-get-connections-in-linkedin)

Comment: I am not sure what's the problem with my program

Comment: Did you look at the links I posted?